# Problem in jenkins installation on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

Tags: 12.04, software-center, jenkins

```
$ sudo apt-get install jenkins
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      jenkins
    0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Need to get 57.8 MB of archives.
    After this operation, 63.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    Get:1 http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/ binary/ jenkins 1.529 [57.8 MB]
    Fetched 57.8 MB in 18s (3,198 kB/s)                                                                               
    Selecting previously unselected package jenkins.
    (Reading database ... 220980 files and directories currently installed.)
    Unpacking jenkins (from .../archives/jenkins_1.529_all.deb) ...
    dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/jenkins_1.529_all.deb (--unpack):
     trying to overwrite '/usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war', which is also in package jenkins-common 1.424.6+dfsg-1ubuntu0.2
    dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                  Errors were encountered while processing:
     /var/cache/apt/archives/jenkins_1.529_all.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can you please help ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get purge jenkins-common
sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

Comment: I see an error: **Package 'jenkins-common' is not installed, so not removed**

Comment: Working on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Also try this command on terminal,

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/jenkins_1.529_all.deb
```