# problem in installing Jenkins: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg

Tags: dpkg, jenkins

when i try to install [Debian-stable](https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/) version of [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/) in **Ubuntu** :

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
jenkins
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

i do [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341955/problem-in-jenkins-installation-on-ubuntu-12-04-3-lts) instructions and execute `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to solve this , but the problem remained

Comment: That question in the link is 7 years old. What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: @David 20.04, but by [this](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/) i now try to check java version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according [this](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/) and [this](https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/) you must install specified version of java:

> 2.164 (2019-02) and newer: Java 8 or Java 11
>
> 2.54 (2017-04) and newer: Java 8
>
> 1.612 (2015-05) and newer: Java 7

> the result must be something like:
>
> ```
> openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9.1+1-post-Debian-1deb10u2)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9.1+1-post-Debian-1deb10u2, mixed mode, sharing)
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Jenkins requires Java in order to run, yet certain distributions don’t include this by default and some Java versions are incompatible with Jenkins.

[Refer the official doc](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/#installation-of-java)

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre
java -version
```